# Security for Flat File CMS (PAAS)

Tags: php

I am building a flat file cms that uses php files. Users will be able to rename files using an input field and the old and new file paths will be sent via ajax to the server where I test for security. I realize this could be done easier with regex or even `OR` operators. I took the `OR` operators out so that the strings would not be too long for this post. And as for regex, I'd like more control over the errors I send back to the client.

The CMS itself is much like a PAAS that resides in directory above all of the individual site folders that each user will have. My goal is to keep users from injecting code that might interfere with other (adjacent) user folders or the cms itself in the parent directory above.

I have not parsed the path's yet for validity. I am just trying to get an idea of how a malicious user might be able to take advantage of what I have written so far.

```
<?php
 $old_path = $_POST['file'].'.php'; // path/to/file.php
 $new_path = $_POST['new_file'].'.php'; // path/to/newfile.php';
  if(strstr($new_path,"<?")){
    echo "Sorry, path cannot contain script tags";
  }elseif(strstr($new_path,"?>")){
    echo "Sorry, path cannot contain script tags";
  }elseif (strstr($new_path,">")){
    echo "Sorry, path cannot contain script tags";
  }elseif (strstr($new_path,"<")){
    echo "Sorry, path cannot contain script tags";    
  }elseif($new_path[0]==="." OR $new_path[0]==='/' OR $new_path[0]==='\\'){
    echo 'Sorry first character of path cannot be a period or slash';
  }else{

    //this is set when the user logs in based on details in a database
    $users_dedicated_directory = $_SESSION['userfolder'].'/';

    // add the users folder when renaming just for more control
    $old_path = $users_dedicated_directory.$old_path;

    // add the users folder when renaming just for more control
    $new_path = $users_dedicated_directory.$old_path;

    rename($old_path,$new_path);

    //trim the users folder name. Send it back to the client  
    echo explode($users_dedicated_directory,$new_path);    
   }   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if `new_path` is something like `a/../../path/to/one/of/you/cms/core/file.php` if think a malicious user could overwrite some files of your CMS.

You'll have to remove write permissions for the web server to nay of your CMS files to prevent that.

Comment: So if I `explode()` the `$new_path` on slashes and check each result of the array to confirm there is not a '.' or a '..', would that prevent this?

Comment: I think there's plenty of risks with de blacklist approach you're using. I'd rather use a white list one with regex only autorizing `[a-zA-Z0-9/]` for instance

Comment: I am not sure I understand blacklist vs. whitelist. How does regex make my if statements more secure? Does regex do something different than `strstr()`? If so, can you explain?

Comment: Blacklist forbid some patterns and whitelist authorise some patterns. Two different approachs but with security in mind and not knowing all the possible flaws of your context, white lists seems a better option. Regex has nothing to do with security. They are just a shorter - and some say simpler - way of checking strings.

Comment: for instance (not tested)
`if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\/]$/', $new_path, $matches) === 1) {...}` prevent malicious user from accessing to parent directory through the usage of '..' in the path